# How to wrap long word inside container using Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, word-wrap

This is my html:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row post img-rounded">
        <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is, the end user selects what is inside the span. If the content inside the span is a very long word, then a horizontal scroll bar appears and the word extends outside of the div. Is there a non-hacky (possibly Twitter Bootstrap 3) way of basically wrapping the word so that it does not extend outside of the div, causing a horizontal scrollbar?

If not, what's the best way to solve the issue?

Comment: add css style `.row span {  word-wrap: break-word }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break, use `word-wrap: break-word`, but you are missing the bootstrap `col-*-*` wrapping the `span`

```css
.row div {
  background: red
}
.row:first-of-type span {
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row post img-rounded">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row post img-rounded">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, is col-*-* really needed? I did `.row span { word-wrap: break-word; }` and it worked.

Comment: would you be able to link to the doc which mentions that it is needed?